# It's a good idea {to go/going}

Tags: verbs, adjectives, sentence-structure, gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund

I have some difficulties understanding when to use the -**ing** form rather than "**to+verb**", because often it seems to me that both are correct.

---

For example:
*John was in favour of visiting the museum.*

I would describe this situation with both:

> John thought it would be a good idea **going** to the museum.

and

> John thought it would be a good idea **to go** to the museum.

A [rule](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-m_infinitive-ing.htm) says I should use *"to+verb"* with adjectives, but I'm not completely sure that apply here, furthermore I find them both to be correct.

- Is there any difference in meaning between the two?
- Is one wrong?
- Am I correctly assuming that "good idea" is an adjective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two sentences have the same meaning, however the first

> John thought it would be a good idea **going to the museum**.

is slightly awkward and would be solved by rewording

> > John thought **going to the museum** ***was*** a good idea.
> >     John thinks going to the museum **is** a good idea.

use the **-ing***(gerund) to describe actual events or experiences

Your second sentence

> John thought it would be a good idea **to go** to the museum.
>   John thinks it is a good idea **to go** to the museum.

is correct and sounds natural.  Use the **to +verb**(infinitive) to describe potential actions

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll try to remember these two "rules".